# How do I sync a local Git repo with a server repo inside VS 2013?

Tags: git, visual-studio

I have just created a new project in VS2013 and added it to source control, choosing the Git option.  This has created the expected hidden .git folder in the root of the solution and the project now shows symbols indicating it is under source control.

I am now wanting to push the whole new solution to another directory, which will eventually become the shared repo.  I got a helpful message in VS, telling me that, to publish my latest commits to a remote repo, I needed to Sync.  I selected this and got a message saying that *'Visual Studio cannot (yet) publish to a non-bare repo.'*

I had already externally run `git init` in the target repo, which I thought would be accepted as a bare empty repo by VS, but it seems not to be the case.  That is a side issue really.  My main problem is that the option to Sync is now greyed-out in VS, even though it claimed that the Sync failed.  Nothing I do seems to get the option back.

Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong and hopefully tell me how to 'fix' this?  Also, if anyone knows of any good documentation specifically dealing with how Git works from within VS, I'd love to hear about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're setting up your remote repository, you should create it using the `--bare` flag.

```
git init --bare <directory>
```

[Atlassian has a small explanation here on the git init options](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository/git-init), which would be good to read, but I would assume that Visual Studio just sees the remote as another repository and doesn't understand how to push to it when not created  as bare.

From the Atlassian article:

> Think of `--bare` as a way to mark a repository as a storage facility,
>   opposed to a development environment. This means that for virtually
>   all Git workflows, the central repository is bare, and developers
>   local repositories are non-bare.

Comment: Thank you for that.  I'll have to remove the whole thing from source control and then start again, as that is the only way I have found so far to get back the greyed-out Sync option.

Comment: @Patrick If you just delete the remote copy, recreate a bare repo, and then resync your existing local repo, you should keep your entire history and not lose anything.